# Access 'this' within Click function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.4

Is it possible to access `$(this)` and perform actions such as `hide()` or `toggle()` this `div` in Knockout? I'm trying to access it via jQuery. Any alternative methods within the function is appreciated.

At the moment if I do this:

```
click: function(){ console.log(this) }
```

I get the `$data` of my viewmodel.

I know other ways of handling this action via the model of knockout but I was wondering if this is possible?

```
  <div data-bind="click: function(){ $(this).hide() }" class="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert" >
         some text here
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost always better to handle logic on the view-model instead of cluttering your markup, however, you can access the element with "$element" instead of "this". For a better example of how things *should* be done refer to Tomalak's excellent answer.

```
data-bind="click: function(){ $($element).hide() }"
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to access $(this) and perform actions such as hide() or toggle() this div in Knockout?

Yes, but you should not do that.

Any jQuery code (beyond the `$.ajax()` utility functions) and any other code that does DOM interaction (modification, traversal, event handling, style changes) should stay completely out of both your viewmodel *and* your view.

- Your viewmodel manages the *state* of your application, not its *looks*.
- The way to manage the looks of the application is by **binding** viewmodel properties to view properties.
- The view should be fully dependent on the viewmodel, but the viewmodel should have zero dependencies on the view.

  - Adding code that calls jQuery `.hide()` in the viewmodel introduces a dependency to the view inside the viewmodel. Assume you change your view and `.hide()` is no longer the right thing to do. Now you have to change the viewmodel as well - without adding any actual functionality.
  - Adding code that calls jQuery `.hide()` in the view leaves the state inside the viewmodel in the dark about a change in how things are displayed. You lose control over how the viewmodel looks and are gradually forced to add even more hacks like this.
- Use the existing bindings (there are bindings all the basic interactions like showing or hiding elements, adding event handlers, interacting with form elements) or [write new bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for special behavior.

So in your case, what you need is

- a viewmodel property that tracks if the item should be visible
- a function to set this property
- the [`visible` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)

In the case of a dialog, let's call that property `isVisible` and let it default to `true`.

Viewmodel:

```
function Alert() {
    var self = this;

    self.isVisible = ko.observable(true);
    self.message = ko.observable("some text here");
    self.dismiss = function () { self.isVisible(false); };
}
```

View, wrapped for legibility:

```html
<div
  data-bind="
    text: message,
    click: dismiss,
    visible: isVisible,
    text: message
  "
  class="alert alert-secondary alert-dismissible fade show"
  role="alert"
></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can pass the `event` and access `event.target` and do `event.target.hide()` on that.
Usually this kind of situation is handled by assigning `this` to some other variable

```
function sample(){
    var _this = this;
    function(){
        console.log(_this,this); // both are accessible here
    }
}
```